# Elastix kernel panic

Tags: linux, elastix

I'm kind of newbie with all the linux stuff.

I have a local server with Elastix 2.5 installed. Everything was running smooth until a few days ago. When I started the server the System didn't boot completely.

I get this error and don't know what to do. I have a SugarCRM database that I need to recover.

```
Found volume group "VolGroup00" using metadata type lvm2
Activating logical volumes
2 logical vomume(s) in volume group "VolGroup00" now active
Trying to resume from /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01
No suspend signature on swap, not resuming.
Creating root filesystem.
EXT3-fs: INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem.
EXT3-fs: write access will be enabled during recovery.
EXT3-fs: invalid journal inode.
mount: error mounting /dev/root on /sysroot as ext3: Invalid argument
Setting up other filesystems.
Setting up new root fs
setuproot: moving /dev failed: No such file or directory
no fstab.sys, mounting internal defaults
setuproot: error mounting /proc: No suc file or directory
setuproot: error mounting /sys: No suc file or directory
Switching to new root and running init.
unmounting old /dev
unmounting old /proc
unmounting old /sys
switchroot: mount failed: No such file or directory
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

Can you please help me out.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Best Regards,
Rafael[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9mJz.jpg)

Comment: Please take the [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). Stack overflow is about programming problems, not problems of programmers. Your question is better suited for http://www.serverfault.com Voting to migrate it there. Please do **NOT** double post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution as can I see, it is booting linux
from another disk (usb/cd/dvd or another connect disk to another linux machine)?
and run fsck.ext3 by hands